# Correct UML diagram for dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, uml

I have following classes:

```
public interface IRule { void Execute(int i); }
public interface IRule1 : IRule { }
public interface IRule2 : IRule { }
public interface IRuleExecutor { void Execute(int i) }

public class Rule1 : IRule1 { public void Execute(int i) { } }
public class Rule2 : IRule2 { public void Execute(int i) { } }

public class RuleExecutor : IRuleExecutor
{
    private ICollection<IRule> allRules;

    public RuleExecutor(ICollection<IRule> rules)
    {
        this.allRules = rules;
    }

    public void Execute(int i) { }
}
```

What is the correct way to display these classes (especially the relationship between RuleExecutor and the rules) in a UML class diagram?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options, but this is how I would model it:

[image: UML diagram]

I haven't explicitly modeled ICollection. It is implicitly represented by the multiplicity "*" on the side of IRule. A rule can be associated with multiple RuleExecutors, so I have put an asterisk on the side of RuleExecutor as well.
The association is directed from RuleExecutor to IRule, because RuleExecutor has a reference to IRule, but not vice versa.

Comment: I have just added "-allRules".

Comment: I have a question: why is the line from Rule1 to IRule1 dotted, but the line from IRule1 to IRule not?

Comment: The dotted is a Realization, the solid a Generalization.